# URLSession completion handler app crashes

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I am using method swizzling for URLSession and below is my swizzled method. I am not sure why app is crashing in target app while executing completion handler for @escaping. Please help me in this.

```
@objc func mytestTaskWithRequest(request: URLRequest,completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void ) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    let completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void = {(data, response, error) in
      if error == nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.captureNetworkInfo(senderRequest: request, senderResponse: response!)
        }
      }
      completionHandler(data,response,nil)
    }
    return mytestTaskWithRequest(request: request,completionHandler: completionHandler)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is on null safety and you force it using !, if the response return null and then your app will be crash
Try this :

```
@objc func mytestTaskWithRequest(request: URLRequest,completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void ) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        let completionHandler: (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void = {(data, response, error) in
          if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              if let tempResponse = response {
               self.captureNetworkInfo(senderRequest: request, senderResponse: tempResponse)
              }
            }
          }
          completionHandler(data,response,nil)
        }
        return mytestTaskWithRequest(request: request,completionHandler: completionHandler)
      }
```